# Rounding in R, possible error

Tags: r, rounding

I was always taught that for numbers 1,2,3 and 4 you round DOWN and for 5,6,7,8 and 9 you round UP. So can someone please explain to me why when using `round` or `signif` in R on 6.5 it rounds it down to 6??

```
round(6.5)
[1] 6
signif(6.5)
[1] 6
```

i need my values to round up when it gives a .5 number. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: hmm ok then....but i NEED my numbers to be rounded up when its .5 so how do i do this automatically?

Comment: Check if you are at a half and use `ceiling` instead of `round`

Comment: @James or even `help("round")` ...

Comment: You could add a very small number to your numbers vector too, something like `round(6.5 + 1e-15)`. `+` is vectorised, so you can add `1e-15` to a whole vector within a single line

Comment: To expand on what @DavidArenburg said, you could do `sign(x) * round(abs(x) + 1e-15)` to account for negative numbers as well.

Comment: thankyou :) i dont suppose you also might know how to round UP any number? e.g. if it is 4.1 then round it up to 5?

Comment: @Summer-JadeGleek'away You want to use `ceiling` for rounding up.

Comment: Just do `?round` and you'll see all the related functions documentaion

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
round2 <- function(x) {
  index <- gregexpr(pattern='\\.', as.character(x)  ) #find the index of the dot
  if ( substr(as.character(x), index[[1]]+1, index[[1]]+1 ) =='5' ) round(x+0.1) else round(x) #check if the first decimal is a 5
}

> round2(5.5)
[1] 6
> round2(255.5)
[1] 256
> round2(-55.5)
[1] -56
```

This seems to be working in any case.

Comment: Maybe replace the 3s with nchar(x) in case it has more or less digits?

Comment: This gets harder, because in general you want to look at the character immediately after the decimal place.  I think I prefer the answers at the linked/duplicate question.

Comment: @BenBolker aaah yes thanks Ben. I will try something else then.

Comment: @docendodiscimus in case I had 4 digits `nchar` wouldn't help though would it?

Comment: True, didn't think it through properly.. Just had the feeling that 3,3 might be too static

Comment: @LyzandeR Would this `sub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", as.character(4.5)) == "5"` work as your condition?

Comment: @blakeoft your way didnt work for x=25.4...

Comment: @BenBolker I think this is more generic now. But probably the dup is better

Comment: @LyzandeR sorry, I meant `sub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", as.character(x)) == "5"`. I had 4.5 in place of x before.

Comment: You should never use text processing functions for mathematical operations.

Comment: @ping miss-typed something. This works now.

Comment: @Roland I agree 100% but isn't this a simple case?

Comment: Why would you do this if you could just use `sign(x) * trunc(abs(x) + 0.5)`, which works also for negative numbers?

Comment: @Roland Only because I hadn't thought about it this way. I added to my answer. Thanks

Comment: That's the top answer to the duplicate question ...

Comment: yep, sorry, my bad...